# Issue with iOS6 if/then statments

Tags: ios, if-statement, ios6

I have an app in iTunes that works fine on iOS 4.3 & 5. In iOS 6, it does not work properly both on actual devices and in the simulator. I have looked at the code and don't see any problems with it. Nevertheless, there seems to be an issue with my if/then statements in iOS6. Functionality of the app is highly dependent on if/then statements such as those below...

```
if (pageTitle.text == @"Alpha")
{
    fieldName.text = @"A";  
    anotherFieldName.text = @"AlphaText";
}

else {}
```

The above changes text based on whether the value of pageTitle.text is "Alpha" nor not. This has worked fine all along. However, in iOS6, even if pageTitle.text equals "Alpha", it will NEVER evaluate to true. Again, this ONLY occurs in iOS6. I have inserted NSLog statements to confirm that pageTitle.text actually equals "Alpha" - and it does. Despite this fact, it never evaluates the above to be true (in other words, NSLog says pageTitle.text equals "Alpha", but the code above will never evaluate pageTitle.text as "Alpha"). This ONLY occurs in iOS6.

Does anyone have any ideas? It seems 'impossible' to me that something as basic as this would have changed in iOS6...but maybe I missed something? Or do you think this could be a bug in iOS6? Any help would be apprceiated. Thank you.

Comment: It's a shame your question got downvoted. I got exactly the same issue when moving to iOS 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if( pageTitle.text == @"Alpha" )
```

Here, you are comparing two **pointers** to objects. One of them is a `NSString` litteral.
Obviously, as you are comparing memory addresses, the comparison will fail.

If you want to test two `NSString` objects for equality, use:

```
if( [ pageTitle.text isEqualToString: @"Alpha" ] == YES )
```

Then you'll have a real string comparison.

Comment: Thank you. I apologize for my error. I will check your solution out and mark this as solved if it resolves the issue. In the meantime, however, could you advise why it worked okay in iOS 4.3 & 5 but not in iOS6? Did something change? Thank you.

Comment: No need to apologise... : ) I guess you were just very lucky... As NSString literals are usually defined only once, if you assigned `pageTitle.text` to a literal, then the comparison with the same literal may maybe succeed, with a lot of luck...  But of course you can't be sure of that, as the property setter implementation may actually copy the object. The compiler may also use different objects for the two literals. In both cases, we'll end with two distinct objects, and the comparison of the pointer addresses using `==` will just fail.

Comment: Right now all uses of the same string literal point to the same NSConstantStringImpl instance at compile time, and a copy of an immutable string remains a pointer to the same object. So even [@"Alpha" copy] is going to work. But yes, it's unreliable because it's an implementation detail.

Comment: Thank you Macmade & Jano so much for the help. I guess I have just been lucky before. Since it suddenly stopped working with iOS6 (and since the NSLog gave the result I expected), I was thinking there was a bug in iOS6. Glad you showed me the correct way so I won't make the same mistake again. I upvoted both your answers and marked this as resolved. (Unfortunately, I was downvoted two times for my question...but I guess it was worth it to have your kind assistance.) Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your code is not in the if-else logic, but in the if condition. The proper way of comparing two strings for equality is:

```
if ([pageTitle.text isEqualToString:@"Alpha"])
{
    fieldName.text = @"A";  
    anotherFieldName.text = @"AlphaText";
}
else 
{
...
}
```

For further discussion about equality vs. identity, read [this.](http://www.karlkraft.com/index.php/2008/01/07/equality-vs-identity/)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I upvoted your answer, but checked Macmade's as answered since I got his first and since he provided the code. Thanks again.